# How to verify the following function is monotonically decreasing?

Tags: inequality, derivatives

We have $\displaystyle 0<\lambda<1, 0<\mu<1$ and $\displaystyle \tau=\frac{\lambda(1-\mu)}{\mu(1-\lambda)}$, therefore, how to verify that the following function $\displaystyle f(\lambda)=\frac{\mu-\lambda}{\mu-\lambda\cdot\tau^B}$ monotonicially decreases with $\displaystyle \lambda$ ? (here $B$ is an integer and $B\geq1$)

Comment: What is $u$? Is it meant to be $\mu$?

Comment: Calling $\tau$ a quantity depending on $\lambda$ and mixing it with the *actual* $\lambda$ is not the smartest notation, in my opinion.

Comment: @Macavity, yes, you're right, thanks for reminding me. I have solved this issue, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I derived that $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda}=\frac{-\mu+\mu\tau^B+B\frac{\mu-\lambda}{1-\lambda}\tau^B}{(\mu-\lambda\tau^B)^2}=\frac{-(\lambda-\mu)^2\cdot\sum\limits_{i=1}^B{i\tau^{i-1}}}{(\mu-\lambda\tau^B)^2\cdot(1-\lambda)^2\cdot\mu}<0$, so that $f$ decreases with $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate $f$ with respect to $\lambda$ and check that the derivative is always positive.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.  Sorry I make the mistake that $f$ decreases with $\lambda$ actually. I know that it can be verified by show the derivative is always negative, how I don't know how to verify.